# reloading dependent modules in Python

Tags: python, reload, python-module

Let's say I have a Python script `main.py` that imports `othermodule.py`. Is it possible to write a `reload(othermodule)` in `main.py` so that when I make changes to `othermodule.py`, I can still just `reload(main)`, which will then reload othermodule?

Comment: I believe `reload`ing the *main* file is a really big mistake...

Comment: If you were to `reload(main)` (which @Bakuriu rightly says is a bad idea), that wouldn't `reload(othermodule)` by default. What are you trying to achieve here? Auto-reloading of any changed modules?

Comment: Yes, sorry I probably didn't explain this very well, but I am just trying to figure out the best way to reload modules in the case that most of my main code is in **main.py** which I import in the interpreter, but **main.py** imports **othermodule.py**, which I might change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's not quite that simple. Assuming you have a `main.py` like this...

```
import time
import othermodule

foo = othermodule.Foo()
while 1:
    foo.foo()
    time.sleep(5)
    reload(othermodule)
```

...and an `othermodule.py` like this...

```
class Foo(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'foo'
```

...then if you change `othermodule.py` to this...

```
class Foo(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'bar'
```

...while `main.py` is still running, it'll continue to print `foo`, rather than `bar`, because the `foo` instance in `main.py` will continue to use the old class definition, although you can avoid this by making `main.py` like this...

```
import time
import othermodule

while 1:
    foo = othermodule.Foo()
    foo.foo()
    time.sleep(5)
    reload(othermodule)
```

Point is, you need to be aware of the sorts of changes to imported modules which will cause problems upon a `reload()`.

Might help to include some of your source code in the original question, but in most cases, it's probably safest just to restart the entire script.

Comment: Thanks, your code example makes sense. The part that I was trying to ask about originally was in regards to the `reload(othermodule)` in that last snippet you have. So if I `reload(main)` in the interpreter after changing **othermodule.py**, would it also `reload(othermodule)` and commit the changes?

Comment: @rottentomato56 Depends on the contents of `main.py`. Assuming the first two lines are `import othermodule` and `reload(othermodule)`, then `reload(main)` should work, but there may be complications, depending on what the actual code is.

Comment: "it's probably safest just to restart the entire script" what if this is a server? Can I do anything better than starting a Python script using `subprocess` and communicating over stdin/stdout?

Answer (score 1):

Python already has [`reload()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) is that not good enough?

From your comments, it sounds as if you might be interested in the [deep reload](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.1/html/interactive/reference.html#dreload) function in `ipython` though I would use it with caution.

Comment: Oh, does reload() also handle imported modules within the main script?

Comment: @rottentomato56 No.`reload` simply "destroys" the module object in `sys.modules` and then re-imports it. If this module imports some other module, this second module is not re-imported since it is already present in `sys.module`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I'll look into this more.